# How to use Onsen UI + Monaca + jQuery

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm new with Onsen UI. I'm using Monaca and I'm trying to work with jQuery.

Below you can check my HTML page and JS script.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br" app="nowa">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" side="right" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px">
</ons-sliding-menu>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="right">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">TEST</div>
        </ons-toolbar>    
        <div ng-controller="menu">
            <div id="test">HELLO!</div>
            <ons-row align="center" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <ons-col>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle perfil-icone"></div>
                        <div>ICON 1</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle exame-icone"></div>
                        <div>ICON 2</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-col>

                <ons-col>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle alerta-icone"></div>
                        <div>ICON 3</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
            <p></p>
            <ons-row align="center" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <ons-col>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle favorito-icone"></div>
                        <div>ICON 4</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle lab-icone"></div>
                        <div>ICON 5</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle rota-icone"></div>
                        <div>ICON 6</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
        </div>
</ons-page>
```

app.js

```
ons.bootstrap();
//ons.disableAutoStatusBarFill();  // (Monaca enables StatusBar plugin by default)

var app = angular.module('nowa', [ 'ngTouch', 'onsen.directives']);

app.controller('menu',function($scope){
    $(function(){
        alert("OI");
        $("#test").html(" USERNAME!");
    });
});
```

The issue is that alert and html commands in javascript code don't work.
What is the issue here? How to use Onsen with Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have to manually include the jQuery.js in the HTML  tag or you'd have to add the Monaca's jQuery Mobile component under "Config" tab (on Monaca IDE) JS/CSS components.

Comment: Thanks! It's working! I don't know why it's not so clear in both docs (Monaca and Onsen UI).

Comment: JFYI. Actually, it's been mentioned in the Monaca Documentation here: http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/en/manual/application/monaca_plugin/.

Comment: I just added jquery in the File | Manage JS/CSS components... I chose Project | JS/CSS components... I chose JQuery (Monaca version) Version 2.03 Where is it?! I cannot find the library in the project... 

And @khemry that link does not exist anymore...

Comment: OK Searched for JQuery on the docs and found this: 
https://docs.monaca.io/en/monaca_ide/tutorial/adding_backend/

Comment: There is also this https://onsen.io/v2/guide/jquery/  but it only explains onsenUI2 and JQuery. Not how to set it up in Monaca.